# permission denied format+en,default+en,i+en,corechart+en.i.js, line 83 character 16

Tags: php, google-visualization, permission-denied

Hi i am also facing the same issue on my site, **In IE 8 the Google chart not displaying** at all..while rendering the chart IE 8 rises the following error,

**permission denied format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.i.js at line 83**

still i cant find why this is happening .please give me a solution for this issue.

**waiting for your valuable suggestions.**

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: Need more info to go on, but off the top of my head, are you trying to write to the document after it is loaded?

Comment: We need to see a working example that demonstrates the problem in order to help you solve this.  Please post the javascript that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and found it occurred when we attempted to remove/refresh the chart. The chart works fine when first rendered on the page but if we cleared the content of the chart this is when the error occurred. The solution for us was to call the clearChart() method on the chart first and then perform any other removing of elements afterwards.